# How Do I Replace Words In a String With Items In a List In Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of words and a string with spaces to put the words in. I need to be able to distribute the items from the list into the spots in the string.

Example:

```
list = ['text', 'be', 'there']

text = "This is an example [word]. Normally there would [word] something important here but [word] isn't."
```

The output would be:

```
"This is an example text. Normally there would be something important here but there isn't."
```

I would need the parts with '[word]' to be replaced with an item from the list.
I am pretty new to python so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Comment: The string method "replace" can replace a given substring in a string by another one. You can also tell it to do it only once. Then you have to wrap this in a for-loop to replace one word after another.

Comment: Let's try not to use Python built-in *list* as the variable name.  It's really bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `re.sub` with custom function:

```py
import re

lst = ["text", "be", "there"]
text = "This is an example [word]. Normally there would [word] something important here but [word] isn't."


text = re.sub(r"\[word\]", lambda _, i=iter(lst): next(i), text)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
This is an example text. Normally there would be something important here but there isn't.
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well. I understand some of it but could you explain what is happening here? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

They advise using the re library here, however, I think it's easier, easier and better to use simple text.format() formatting

Code example:

```py
list_of_words = ['text', 'be', 'there']

text = "This is an example {}. Normally there would {} something important here but {} isn't.".format(*list_of_words)
```

The output will look like this:

```
This is an example text. Normally there would be something important here but there isn't.
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the input string needs to have all occurrences of `[word]` replaced with `{}` first, and that the input string cannot contain `{}` itself.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.sub` along with a callback function:

```py
list = ['text', 'be', 'there']
text = "This is an example [word]. Normally there would [word] something important here but [word] isn't."
output = re.sub(r'\[word\]', list.pop(0), text)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
This is an example text. Normally there would be something important here but there isn't.
```

The strategy here is that for each `[word]` match, we call `pop(0)` on the list of replacements.  This returns the first element in that list, while also removing it and queueing up the next replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input string by `[word]`, zip the resulting list with the input list, flatten the pairs and join them for output:

```
words = ['text', 'be', 'there']
text = "This is an example [word]. Normally there would [word] something important here but [word] isn't."

print(''.join(w for p in zip(text.split('[word]'), (*words, '')) for w in p))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/yMdSOA